# Using XACT in C++/Direct X for a simple 2D game

Tags: c++, audio, directx, effects, xact

I'm trying to take sound effects I have made and put them into my game. I have a sound like walking that I want to loop while the user is walking and once the user stops walking, I want the sound to stop. I went through the DirectX tutorials on using XACT but it does not answer my question. In my code I try to use the play function and when they are not moving i stop the walking sound. What happens with this is it just plays the whole sound clip even when i stop moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `XACT_FLAG_STOP_IMMEDIATE` flag?

Comment: AHH I see now I was able to get it to stop imdiatly. I was just passing 0 to that flag.

Comment: Now i Need to figure out how to loop the sound when it compleats as long as the user is moving.

Comment: The wave file itself can be marked as looping, or you can set `nLoopCount` to a big number when you PrepareWave.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203895(XNAGameStudio.20).aspx  - look for the section where you can set the wave properties to Infinite looping.